# Efficient way to test bits in a byte array using a union?

Tags: c++, arduino, avr-gcc

I have data that is sometimes best viewed as an array of 10 bytes, sometimes as an array of 80 bits. Maybe a job for a union?

After filling the array with 10 bytes, I scan through the 80 bits and test if set. The scan is advanced bit-by-bit in an ISR, so efficiency is key.

Right now I do this at each interrupt:

```
 volatile uint8_t bit_array[10]; // external to ISR
 volatile uint8_t bit_idx;
 volatile uint8_t byte_idx;
 
 // -----ISR---------
 
 static uint8_t abyte;   // temp byte from array

 if (bit_idx == 0) {     // at each new byte
   bit_idx = 1;          // begin at the lowest bit
   abyte = bit_array[byte_idx];
 }
 if (abyte & bit_idx) {
   // << do the thing >>
 }
 if ((bit_idx *= 2) == 0) { // idx << and test for done
   if (++byte_idx > 9) {    // try next byte
     byte_idx = 0;
     fill_array_again();
   }
 }
```

I have a sense that there's a way to create a union that would allow a straightforward scan of the bits using a single index 0..79, but I don't know enough to try it.

The questions are: can I do that? and: can it be efficient?

Comment: There is no efficient method for bit testing, whether using a Union or hand coding.  Usually, the compiler will use a standard technique of masking and bit testing.  The union technique is usually easier on the developer to code.

Comment: The net efficiency depends on the processor instruction set.  Some processors have instructions to test bits; others require an AND and branch instructions.

Comment: If many bits are 0 then you can use `a & (a - 1)` to mask the lowest set bit and a lookup table to get the index of the bit if your cpu doesn't have a bit count opcode. `uint16_t` or larger could also improve things. Measure it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - in this case the compiler is avr-gcc and the micro is ATmega328p (no tag for that)

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow - The requirement is strictly to examine each bit in turn, in order, from an array of 10 bytes.

Comment: That isn't reflected in the code: `if (abyte & bit_idx) { // << do the thing >> }` You do nothing when the bit is 0. And if that is something that gets called every time one of the bits get set then skipping the 0 bits will be a huge improvement. You could even check each byte for 0 before testing individual bits.

Comment: On the Raspberry Pi there are 3 32bit registers containing interrupt bits and that's how I check them there too. First check if any bits are set and if so then skip all the 0 bits.

Comment: For a moment I read that as "Maybe a job for a unicorn" (sorry, it's late here).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow - I appreciate the thought, but it doesn't apply here: the bits must each be accessed, in order. 'Doing nothing' can sometimes be an affirmative act (-:

Comment: Then your code is already broken. The variable is not volatile despite what the comment says. And even if it were the compiler would access it as bytes. If the bits need to be accessed then you need inline asm that uses a bit access.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow - the comment says it's volatile because it is, in the much larger code from which this is abstracted. I'll edit to reflect that. The code does work correctly, I'm just looking for efficiency improvements.

Comment: You should check closely if reading the data as bytes isn't sufficient. Copying the `volatile uitn8_t` into a `uint8_t` and then checking each bit will probably be a lot faster. And I really can't think of anything on AVR that would require you read each bit in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `0 ... 79` range for your index without the need for a union<sup>1</sup>. You can get the **byte index** in your array using `index / 8` and the **bit position** (within that byte) using `index % 8`.

This would certainly *simplify* your code; however, whether it will be significantly more efficient will depend on a number of factors, like what the target CPU is and how smart your compiler is. But note that the division and remainder operations with `8` as their RHS are trivial for most compilers/architectures and reduce to a bit-shift and a simple mask, respectively.

Here's a possible outline implementation:

```cpp
uint8_t data[10]; // The 10 bytes
uint8_t index = 0; // index of bits in 0 .. 79 range

void TestISR()
{
    // Test the indexed bit using combination of division and remainder ...
    if (data[index / 8] & (1 << (index % 8))) {
        // Do something
    }
    // Increment index ...
    if (++index > 79) {
        index = 0;
        refill_array();
    }
}
```

For any compiler that fails to implement the optimized division and remainder operations, the `if` statement can be re-written thus:

```cpp
    if (data[index >> 3] & (1 << (index & 7))) {
        // ...
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that any attempt to actually use a union will likely exhibit undefined behaviour. In C++, reading from a member of a union that wasn't the last one written is UB (although it's acceptable and well-defined in C).

Comment: I initially had something similar, but it seemed as though it required more computation. It's hard to profile code in an ISR in the Arduino environment. I can, however, instrument this with port pokes and see what an o'scope says.

Comment: Another case of 'don't try to out-think the compiler'. I haven't tested for speed vs the original code (yet), but I did see that your version with arithmetic emits 4 bytes less code than the one with shifts.

Comment: Just FYI, I scoped the original vs this code and the original is about 2x faster (~2 uSec vs ~4 uSec) , at the expense of 20 bytes of code. Your example is simpler and easier to understand, but I need the speed.